# PHP: gethostbyname bug

Tags: php, ip, gethostbyname

I am using `gethostbyname()` to get the ip address of domains in an application.

In some cases invalid addresses like '50.9.49' are checked also.

```
echo gethostbyname('50.9.49'); // returns 50.9.0.49
```

In this cases `gethostbyname` should return false or the unmodified invalid ip address. however the functions returns the modified IP address `50.9.0.49`.

Looks like a bug in php. The quick fix seems to be to check for invalid numerical addresses before, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: I think PHP is not the only place where this happens. It also happens when using `ping 50.9.49` in Windows. I get the response: `Pinging 50.9.0.49 with 32 bytes of data...`

Comment: @Simon In that case its not bug

Comment: it's not a bug ... it's a feature! ;-)

Comment: And `ping 173.1` would actually `ping 173.0.0.1`.

Comment: Its some kind  assuming `0`s  in the middle to make it 4 byte long address.

Comment: @harald: Indeed, for the ones who are too  lazy to type an extra zero.

Comment: I believe we have discovered an `undocumented feature` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP's `gethostbyname` actually [uses](http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_4/lcov_html/standard/dns.c.gcov.php) the results of the underlying OS's `gethostbyname`, e.g., from Linux's `netdb.h` or Windows' `Winsock2.h`. It's those functions that actually produce the return value, not PHP.

```
/* {{{ php_gethostbyname */
static char *php_gethostbyname(char *name)
{
    struct hostent *hp;
    struct in_addr in;

    hp = gethostbyname(name);

    if (!hp || !*(hp->h_addr_list)) {
        return estrdup(name);
    }

    memcpy(&in.s_addr, *(hp->h_addr_list), sizeof(in.s_addr));

    return estrdup(inet_ntoa(in));
}
/* }}} */
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is an undocumented feature for how IPs works. As mentioned in the comments for your question, `ping 50.9.49` in Windows actually pings `50.9.0.49`. If you enter an adress as `a.b.d`, it automatically inserts a zero as `c`: `a.b.0.d`. If you just enter `a.d`, two zeroes are inserted: `a.0.0.d`.

This has been tested with both Windows 7 and Debian Linux.

Comment: It actually goes further than that -- the third "octet" is treated as a 16-bit value. Pinging `1.2.772` gets you `1.2.3.4`, since 772 is 0x0304. Indeed, you can `ping 16909060` (0x01020304) to get the same result!

Comment: `ping 50` gets you `0.0.0.50`.